# The positive solution of $a x e^{2x} + b x e^x - c = 0$ where $a,c > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, lambert-w

I've stumbled upon the equation
$$f(x) := a x e^{2x} + b x e^x - c = 0$$
where $a,c > 0$ while doing my research. I'm only interested in the positive solution, i.e. $x>0$. It is easy to show a unique positive solution exists since $f(0)=-c < 0$ and if $f(x_0) > 0$ then $f(x)>0, \forall x\geq x_0$ (obviously such $x_0$ exists). This shows the existence of the unique positive solution because of continuity.

I'm interested in the analytical expression of the solution (if such an expression exists). I tried to put this equation in one of the forms in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.08910.pdf without any luck.

Is there any known solution to this kind of equation or am I stuck with numerical solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a>0$, WLOG we can fix it as $a=1$ and
consider zeros of the function
with two parameters instead of three,
\begin{align} 
f(x) &= x \exp(2x) + \alpha x \exp(x) - \beta = 0
\tag{1}
\end{align}
where
$\alpha=\tfrac{b}{a}$, $\beta=\tfrac{c}{a}$.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a closed form solution for (1),
but the numeric can be just fine.
As a heuristic for initial guess of the positive root of (1)
the root $x_0$ of a closely related equation

\begin{align} 
f_2(x) &= x^2 \exp(2x) + \alpha x \exp(x) - \beta = 0
,
\tag{2}
\end{align}
which has a positive root,
\begin{align} 
x_0&=
\operatorname{W}\Big(-\tfrac12\,\alpha+\tfrac12\,\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\beta}\Big)
,
\end{align}
can be used.

Here is an example `python` code, which uses
[Halley's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method)
to iteratively find the approximation of the root of (1)
for $\alpha=1.2$, $\beta=1.6$,
which is approximately $x\approx 0.39903258116278510968$:

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 20
exp=decimal.getcontext().exp

from scipy.special import lambertw as W
from numpy.lib.scimath import sqrt as sqrt

a=1.2; b=1.6
alpha = decimal.Decimal(a)
beta = decimal.Decimal(b)
 
def f(x):
  return x*exp(2*x) + alpha*x*exp(x) - beta

def df(x):
  return exp(x)*((1+2*x)*exp(x)+alpha*(1+x))

def ddf(x):
  return exp(x)*(4*exp(x)*(1+x)+alpha*(2+x))

def F(x):
  fx=f(x)
  dfx=df(x)
  ddfx=ddf(x)
  return x-2*fx*dfx/(2*dfx**2-fx*ddfx)

def fx0():
  return W(1/2*(-a+sqrt(a*a+4*b))).real

x=decimal.Decimal(fx0()); print(x)
# 0.49006785880157982537

x=F(x); print(x)
x=F(x); print(x)
x=F(x); print(x)
x=F(x); print(x)

# 0.39948996502974891810
# 0.39903258122349558881
# 0.39903258116278510968
# 0.39903258116278510968
```

And this is a contour plot of solutions of (1)
for $\alpha\in[-3,3]$, $\beta\in[0,6]$, $x=0.1,\dots,1.2$:

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice approach ! $\to +1$ for sure.